# Passing Segue Gives Error

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sdk

Hi I have currently made a push on select to get my table view to push to a detail view. I also have this code to send the name of the table cell that was selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *acell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedCell = acell.textLabel.text;

    DetailViewController *myDetViewCont = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    myDetViewCont.navigationItem.title = selectedCell;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myDetViewCont animated:YES];

}
```

It builds successfully but in the simulator It throws an error:

```
@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
Thread: 1 signal: SIGABRT
```

I've looked up similar problems but havent found a solution.
Any Help?

Ok additional info on the error:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myDetViewCont animated:YES];
```

Comment: Xcode is really annoying about how it handles uncaught exceptions during debugging.  Go to its Breakpoint navigator and click '+' at the bottom.  Add a break on Objective-C exceptions and let's see if it gives better information.

Comment: I just realized...you said 'segue' but you're loading a controller from a nib.  That doesn't quite make sense.  (But I still stand by my Xcode comment!)

Comment: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myDetViewCont animated:YES];`   Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1

Comment: Great...does it also write a reason to the console?  (Here's a guess: is `myDetViewCont` nil by any chance?)

Comment: Where would I check for any more details? I dont think its null. I have a DetailViewController class.

Comment: Also I am not using nib files but a storyboard and objective-c classes

Comment: You can use `NSLog(@"Detail: %@", myDetViewCont);` to be sure but, if you're really calling `initWithNibName:` without any nib files, I'm now thinking nil/null is very likely.

Comment: I get `2012-08-14 11:28:32.885 CCBuilder[1311:c07] Detail: <DetailViewController: 0x7473100>
(lldb)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using storyboards, then the following line doesn't make sense:

```
DetailViewController *myDetViewCont = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Do you have a NIB file called `DetailViewController.xib` in your project? Presumably not.  Thus `myDetViewCont` will be `nil` and you'll get an exception. If you do have that NIB, then what is the push segue going between (because you can't segue from a storyboard to a NIB)?

Assuming that you really want to use storyboards, and not NIBs, if you already have a push segue between the controllers, give that segue an identifier (you do this in Interface Builder; in my code below I'll just use `youridentifier` as a placeholder for whatever you specify, which you'll replace with the correct identifier) and then you should transition using the segue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *acell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"youridentifier" sender:acell];
}
```

If you want to send data to the new controller, you'd use `prepareForSegue` to do that:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"youridentifier"])
    {
        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            UITableViewCell *selectedCell = sender;
            UIViewController *myDetViewCont = segue.destinationViewController;
            myDetViewCont.navigationItem.title = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog("%s Was expecting sender to be a tableviewcell", __FUNCTION__);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So would I use both of the scripts if I wanted to send data. I would like to send the acell in the first script.

Comment: Yes. The first method is for performing the segue. The second is for passing the data. (The reason for two methods is that with segues you often don't need the first one, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. When you use Interface Builder to hook up a segue between a `UITableViewCell` and another scene, it will perform the segue for you and no code is necessary. It's not clear how you've set up your segue. Did you do it just between the two scenes themselves, in which case you need `didSelectRow...`, or between the `UITableViewCell` in the first scene and the second scene, in which case you don't?)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this. You need to have a UINavigationController in your story board. To do this take your first scene, click on it and go to tabs at top of xcode and do Editor>Embed in>Navigation controller, check the button to set the navigation controller as inital scene. Add the following code to hide the navbar at top.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```